# Extract a weekday() from an SQLAlchemy InstrumentedAttribute (Column type is datetime)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an SQLAlchemy DB column which is of type datetime:

`type(<my_object>) --> sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute`

How do I reach the actual date in order to filter the DB by `weekday()` ?

Answer (score 6):

I got it:
`from sqlalchemy import func`
`(func.extract(<my_object>, 'dow') == some_day)`

dow stands for 'day of week'
The extract is an SQLAlchemy function allowing the extraction of any field from the column object.

Comment: On postgresql it was the opposite, `func.extract('dow', <my_object>)` which is consistent with postgresql's actual syntax `extract('dow' from DATE)`